# Trying to save output from WavePlayers in processing

Tags: java, audio, processing

I'm making an addition to some code to save an audio file of some data that is being outputted by a simulation I am running in Processing.

In my setup(), I run

```
try {
    AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(44100.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
    Sample s = new Sample(af, 44100);
    rts = new RecordToSample(ac, s, RecordToSample.Mode.FINITE);
  }
```

but the code does not run because of the compiler error 
the constructor "Sample(AudioFormat, int)" does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet as is looks fine, can you make sure that you have the following import:

```
import beads.*; // import the beads library
```

Sample class is actually part of the [Beads](http://www.beadsproject.net/) library (refer to [Java docs](http://www.beadsproject.net/doc/net/beadsproject/beads/data/Sample.html)), and not Processing. Therefore if you do not have the Beads library imported in your project, the Sample class will not be recognised.

Instructions to using Beads with Processing:

1. Download Beads [library for Processing](http://www.beadsproject.net/downloads/Beads_Processing.zip).
2. Follow instructions inside the README.txt file.